# How to limit preprocess functions base on a theme?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm working on a theme that using `hook_preprocess_node` and `hook_preprocess_page` and everything is working fine. However, whenever I go to any admin pages, it's throwing me some errors because the array changes. So what I'm trying to achieve is to add a condition only to run this preprocess function if using my theme.

How can I limit the preprocess function base on my theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check theme active with function:

```
<?php

$active = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
```

Get list all themes with:

```
<?php

$themes = \Drupal::service('theme_handler')->listInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the preprocess functions in your theme's `template.php` file, those will only be executed on the pages where the theme is applied.
So, if your admin theme is different (which is the case almost every time), the preprocess functions from your site theme would not be executed.

Comment: I'm on D8 so I'm not using `template.php` instead I'm using `.theme`. Which I do not think that it matters.  My admin theme is different and the process function are still been execute. =(. I will add more information about the errors that I'm getting.

Comment: Oops.. Didn't see the 8 tag on the question. The preprocess functions are technically specific to the theme. Not sure why are they executing on a different theme. It will be good if you could add the code which you are trying out.

Comment: mytheme.theme and mymodule.module files are run on every page load, when the corresponding theme/module is activated.